# How do I Solve This Kind of Differential Equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve this differential equation? $$y(2x+y^2)dx+x(y^2-x)dy=0$$

Comment: Integrating Factor.

Answer (score 5):

By dividing the equation by $y^2dx$ and reordering the terms, the equation can be written in the following form:
$$(y + xy')+\left(\frac{2x}{y}-\frac{x^2 y'}{y^2}\right) = 0\tag{1}$$
Integrating both sides of the equation with respect to $x$ gives:
$$ xy + \frac{x^2}{y} = K \tag{2}$$
Which is a quadratic equation with the following solution:
$$ y = \frac{-K\pm\sqrt{K^2-4x^3}}{2x}.\tag{3}$$

$\hspace2in$[image]
$\hspace2in$A plot of the solutions for $K\in\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}.$

Comment: -1 There is no explanation, this will not help anyone who doesn't know how to do this already.

Comment: @eBusiness: Honestly I don't know what kind of explanation to add, I just played a bit with the original differential equations till getting something that looked integrable. $(1)\Rightarrow(2)$ is straightforward, and $(2)\Rightarrow(3)$ is straightforward, too.

Comment: What kind of transformations did you use? Perhaps with links to relevant articles. The only one that doesn't look totally arbitrary to me is the final transformation.

Comment: @eBusiness: To get $(1)$, I just divided the original differential equation by $y^2 dx$, no transformations at all!

Comment: That _is_ a transformation.

Comment: $\phantom{}$ -.-" Feel free to add "by dividing both terms of the original differential equation by $y^2\,dx$ we get $(1)$:"...

Comment: Can you please specify the variable wrt which you are integratin? because (1) has different variables in each term..

Comment: Done ;)$\phantom{}$

Comment: But there is no explicit assumption that y is not a function of x....

Comment: $y$ *is* a function of $x$. $$\frac{d}{dx}(xy) = xy'+y,\qquad \frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{y}=\frac{2x}{y}-\frac{x^2 y'}{y^2}.$$

Comment: Should I add that $y'$ means $\frac{dy}{dx}$?